# Що за Пілікок сидить на Пілікокській горі?

Tags: переклад, from-english, власні-назви, іноземні-імена, невідоме-слово

Джерело: В.Шекспір. Твори в шести томах: Том 5. К.: Дніпро, 1986. 696 с. - С.: 235-343. Переклад М. Рильського:

> **Едгар**  *Пілікок* сидів на *Пілікокській* горі. Ух, ух, ух!
>
> **Блазень**  Ця  ніч холодна  всіх  нас  оберне  на  дурнів  та
>   шаленців біснуватих.

На перший погляд, ґуґл нічого не знає про це слово, видає німецький і білоруський переклади Шекспіра.

В ориґіналі написано таке:

> **Edg.** Pilicock sat on Pilicock hill; — Haloo, loo, loo.

Виходить так, що замість перекласти Рильський просто транслітерував цю власну назву, чому?

Comment: *«Edg. Pilicock fat on Pilicock hill; — Haloo, loo, loo.»* А яким чином це запитання стосується української мови? Це власна назва. Ви запитуєте, чому перекладач переклав *Pilicock* українською як *Пілікок*, а не *Бурмоковт/Бармаглот*? :)

Comment: @bytebuster там все не так просто, ось зараз читаю цю статтю: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.874.4521&rep=rep1&type=pdf
 може, сам і відповім. а питання зараз відредаґую.

Comment: До оновлення. А чому слово *„Manchester“* просто транслітерують у *«Манчестер»*? Здавалося-б, українською мало б ся бути *«Ліверпуль»*… Я продовжую вважати, що це запитання, у тому вигляді, як воно сформульоване, не є про українську мову. Якби мій close-vote не був вирішальним, **би-м проголосував за закриття** з причини off topic.

Comment: @bytebuster тут з транслітерацією без перекладу зникає гра слів, не бачу зносок у такому разі, думаю, робота була недороблена упорядниками - то ж ми маємо тут її довершити своїми власними дослідженнями й пояснити Пілікок, незрозумілий в іншому разі тим, хто читає Короля Ліра.

Answer (score 3):

Якшчо точніше, то пйеса [Король Лір](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%9B%D1%96%D1%80), четверта сцена, третьої дії.

[Оріґінал](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/lear/page_164.html)

> Pillicock sat on Pillicock hill. Alow, alow, loo, loo!

Пояснення

- pillicock = penis — прутень;
- pillicock hill = vulva — піхва;

---

Доповнення через онову автором запитання.

Перекладач міг цілком обіграти українського штибу

> І встромив кінь свою головіньку в колодязь за водою. Сьорб, сьорб!

Але схоже він так не міг, бо то були радянські часи

> К.: Дніпро, 1986. 696 с. - С.: 235-343.

Отже прояв націяльного чи чогось некультурного, скоріш за все, було під цензурою.

Comment: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.874.4521&rep=rep1&type=pdf тут вирішили посперечатися з таким тлумаченням, наприклад.

Comment: Се джерело теж [підтверджує](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cock) ／ _Pillicock_: 1530s, dialectal variant of Middle English pillicock, see → _Cock_: Slang sense of “penis” is attested since 1610s (but compare pillicock "penis," from c. 1300); Дата пйеси 1605.

Comment: так, але важлива засторога, що це неточно.

Answer (score 1):

Знайшов, як це написано в ориґіналі:

> **EDGAR** *Pillicock* sat on *Pillicock* hill. Alow, alow, loo, loo!

а тоді знайшов і [дослідження](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.874.4521&rep=rep1&type=pdf) етимолоґії цього слова:

Автор каже, що навіть Оксфордський словник анґлійської мови (ОСАМ) не може надати достатньо переконливої етимолоґії цього слова, хоч і каже, що це пеніс/прутень.

Незважаючи на це, дослідник все-таки схиляється до думки, що це все має сексуальний підтекст, бо:

> the first record of the vulgar sense of cock in the OED is 1616 (1972 Supplement), it is tempting to suppose that this sense may have been in use considerably earlier and thus that the specific form of pillicock has been influenced by folk etymology

Переклад: перше вульґарне застосування слова "cock" у ОСАМ датується 1616 роком (видання 1972 року), і дуже хочеться припустити, що цей смисл цього слова був у вжитку значно раніше, а тому окремі форми слова "pillicock" зазнали впливу народної етимолоґії

і потім:

> The fifteenth-century lyric, "I have a Gentle Cock" (Robbins
>   1952:41-42) seems to imply this sense: "& euery nyзt he perchit hym
>   / in myn ladyis chaumbyr" (19-20). The sexual voracity of the cock
>   was proverbial in the fourteenth century;

Переклад: слова пісні 15 сторіччя "I have a Gentle Cock" (Robbins
1952:41-42), здається, мають саме це значення:"& euery nyзt he perchit hym
/ in myn ladyis chaumbyr" (19-20). Сексуальна ненажерливість півня мала крилате значення у 14 сторіччі.

Тому можемо вважати, хоч і з певними засторогами, що, як і написав follower:

- pillicock = penis — прутень;
- pillicock hill = vulva — піхва;

Це підтверджується і контекстом. Король Лір перед цим каже:

> Батьки Самі потвор нещасних породили

Тоді Едгар відповідає фразою про прутні й піхви (або хтозна що ще).